# SQL syntax error: can't be found

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

I'm new to SQL so i'm probably missing something. Apparently I have a syntax error on this line:

```
 $mysql = 'INSERT INTO Orders (Name, Recipient, Destination, Room, Message, Anonymous, OffCampus, OffCampusAddress) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
```

Could anyone help me identify what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1

Here is my parameter binding:

```
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssssss', $name, $recipient, $destination, $room, $message, $anonymous, $offcampus, $offcampusaddress);
```

Comment: Post the error in your post

Comment: Sorry about that, just added

Comment: Where is your [mysqli_stmt_bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)?

Comment: Try to put "`" on the column names

Comment: I suggest you do this mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, @binders) and place into @binders all your values, easier to read and understand as well as debug

Comment: I added the mqsqli_stmt_bind_param, and the back ticks didn't help

Comment: What is your programming language? is it ``c`` ? ``php`` ?

Answer (score 1):

It should look like this:

```
 $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');
 $mysql = "INSERT INTO Orders\n" + 
          "(Name, Recipient, Destination, Room, Message, Anonymous, OffCampus, OffCampusAddress)\n" + 
          "VALUES\n" + 
          "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $mysql);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssssss', $name, $recipient, $destination, $room, $message, $anonymous, $offcampus, $offcampusaddress);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: is that a question? or a statement?

Comment: It's a statement, sorry. The question mark expresses my confusion about the situation haha

Comment: Try to use the statement (modified) I just put, by splitting it into several lines, the error code (line) will be more clear where the problem is

Comment: BTW obviously, you did set the value for $name, $recipient, etc?

Comment: I now get: mysqli error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1

Comment: and yes, I have set all the values

Comment: Try with ``"`` rather than `

Comment: neither works for me, die('mysqli error1: '.mysqli_error($con)); throws an error

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'

Comment: Try to statically write the values, rather than use `?` see if it solves the error

Answer (score 0):

Try to add ` for column names and ' for values. it may work

Comment: I think @Sivaguru don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I think your any one of values may contain ' quotes. Did you used mysqli_real_escape_string for values?

Comment: he is using binders, so the value itself doesn't have any influence even if it has quotes

Comment: I used str_replace to replace any instances of "'" in any of the values

Comment: since you are using binders, the value cannot cause an SQL injection or an SQL error, so no need to replace